# Properties of a supremum of a parametrized set II

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Please I need help with this question:

$E(x)= \left \{ \left(1+ \frac{x}{n} \right)^n : n \in \mathbb{N} \right \}$.
Let $a(x) = \sup E(x)$ (least upper bound).

($1$) Prove that $a(x) < a(y)$ if $0 < x < y$.

(2) Prove that $a(x)a(y) \leq \left( a \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) \right) ^ 2$.

(3) Prove that $a(x + y) = a(x) \cdot a(y)$.

I already proved that $E(x)$ has no largest element and that it's bounded above. I also proved the first two parts. And I know that E(x) is bounded by e^x and thus supE(x) = e^x = a(x), so a(y) = e^y. Can you please help me in proving the third part?

Thank you.

Comment: So if you managed to prove that $e^x = a(x)$, you can just prove the exponential property via the definition, which I am assuming you are using the series expansion definition.

Comment: is it how it's done? :"a(x+y) = e^(x+y) and a(x)a(y) = (e^x)(e^y) = e^(x+y), so a(x+y) = a(x)a(y)

Comment: Just as an aside remark, it seems from what you wrote that you've just shown that $E(x)$ is bounded from above by $e^x$, and not that it's the least upper bound. If you haven't shown (by some method) that it is the least upper bound, then you've not yet shown that $a(x)=e^x$.

Comment: i have shown this

Comment: is it how we solve part 3 ? a(x+y) = e^(x+y) and a(x)a(y) = (e^x)(e^y) = e^(x+y), so a(x+y) = a(x)a(y)

Comment: No what you showed is $sup E(x) \leq e^x$

Comment: i can show that supE(x) = e^x, but how can i solve part 3?

Comment: Doesn't look like to me you did, but like I said in the first comment. It depends on your definition of $e^x$. maybe you should write down what you did for (i) and (ii).

Comment: A previous version of the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3103555/proof-concerning-general-topology-sets-and-supremum).